# Некорректная ширина, получаемая через element.offsetWidth / scrollWidth

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Написал небольшой скрипт для горизонтальной прокрутки таблицы, который еще добавляет определенней класс, когда таблица полностью прокручена, но для того, чтобы он корректно работал, нужна фактическая ширина таблицы с учетом скролла (на ней стоит css свойство overflow-x: hidden;). Но браузер, по какой-то причине, передает размеры отличные от фактических. Причем, если долго перезагружать таблицу, то иногда передаются и корректные данные. Если через инспектор выбрать элемент, то ширина всегда корректная и неизменная. В чем может быть причина?

```
//Горизонтальная прокрутка таблицы
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', horizontalTableScrolling);

function horizontalTableScrolling (){
    const width = document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow');
    const scrollWidth = document.querySelector('.table__main').scrollWidth;
    const buttons = document.querySelector('.wires-table__button-wrapper');
    addClasses()
    buttons.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.attributes[1].value === 'right'){
            width.scrollLeft += 40
            addClasses()
        }else if(e.target.attributes[1].value === 'left'){
            width.scrollLeft -= 40
            addClasses()
        }
    })
    function addClasses() {
        console.log(scrollWidth, width.offsetWidth, width.scrollLeft);
        if(width.scrollLeft === 0){
            width.classList.add('wires-table__shadow_left');
            width.classList.remove('wires-table__shadow_center');
        }else if(scrollWidth - width.offsetWidth === width.scrollLeft){
            width.classList.remove('wires-table__shadow_center');
            width.classList.add('wires-table__shadow_right');
        }else{
            width.classList.add('wires-table__shadow_center');
            width.classList.remove('wires-table__shadow_right', 'wires-table__shadow_left');
        }
    }
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        let delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.wheelDelta || -e.detail));
        document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow').scrollLeft -= delta * 40;
        e.preventDefault();
        addClasses()
    }
    if (document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow').addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow').addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.querySelector('.wires-table__shadow').attachEvent('onmousewheel', scrollHorizontally);
    }
};
```

Comment: IE 6/7/8? Ты из какого года этот год достал?

Comment: Webpack используется?

Comment: Кстати, да! Фичи querySelector, classList, offsetWidth, console.log не поддерживаются IE 6-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, замените offsetWidth на clientWidth.

Должно получиться как-то так:

```
if(e.target.scrollLeft >= e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.clientWidth - 1){
   width.classList.remove('wires-table__shadow_center');
   width.classList.add('wires-table__shadow_right');
}
```

Во-вторых, addClasses лучше запускать по событию **scroll**, а не по событию **mousewheel**.

Песочница https://jsfiddle.net/q1fos0ev/

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало! Только в твоем примере, сначала удаляются все классы, а потом через тернарный оператор добавляется новый.  Это не производительно. Получается, что при каждом скролле по-любому будет удалятся класс, вне зависимости от позиции. Лучше, все таки, сначала проверять позицию и уже потом удалять/добавлять.

Comment: @mr.smile я бы даже сделал вот так https://jsfiddle.net/rd6vh05f/ но и это не обязательно. Ведь по окончании работы процедуры класс не менялся. Перерисовка не требуется.

Comment: Нет, пересчёт всего без классов действительно будет, потому что считывание идёт после снятия классов. А вот у второго варианта, наверное, не будет. // сс @mr.smile

Comment: @Qwertiy ну как же? код синхронный, пока выполнение функции не закончится, следующий кадр генерировать не начнёт. Разве не так?

Comment: @DiD, нет, не так. Точнее, reflow произойдёт. На самом деле даже два раза. А вот обновления экрана действительно не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что такое reflow? где его посмотреть? для тестов заменил код с события scroll на const viewport = document.querySelector('.viewport')
  setInterval(()=>{
          viewport.className='viewport border-green';
          viewport.className='viewport border-blue';
          viewport.className='viewport border-red';
  },1); Далее запускаю профилирование. У меня отображает лишь нано-нагрузки от Compositior, но только когда я двигаю мышкой. Если мышь не дергать - Compositior тоже не нагружает. Браузер Google Chrome. Версия 87.0.4280.11 (Официальная сборка), dev (x86_64)

Comment: @DiD, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF4Fs.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вам не трудно будет убрать весь JS-код, сделать элемент "не-скролящимся" и запустить карусель стилей принудительно по setInterval как в моем предыдущем сообщении, чтобы по завершению функции класс оставался таким же как и был до начала выполнения функции, при этом менялся в ходе ее выполнения? Это чтобы убрать ненужные шумы из статистики профилирования для объективной картины.

Comment: Я даже подготовлю весь код странички для вас тут https://pastebin.com/6wuQccXa

Comment: @DiD, в последнем коде нет считывания scrollTop.

Comment: @Qwertiy так дело то не в scrollTop, а в классах. Скроллинг - это вообще побочный шум, от которого и предлагается избавиться. Cделалось несколько скриншотов (по 3 на каждый браузер): https://imgur.com/a/3w2rKvU обратите внимание на закоментированные строчки в скриптах - сначала идет 4 изменения класса, потом - 1 изменение класса и последние - вообще без изменения класса.

Comment: @DiD, нет, дело именно в srollTop.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ок, повторю эксперимент с активным скроллом